# can not write data into an sql table,

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I am trying to write some information into an SQL database from my website using PHP. I can access the database to login, however I can not write anything to it from my website.  Also, I can not view any connection errors.

Form Page:

```
<?php
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$hostname.';dbname='.$dbname, $user, $pass);

if (!$dbh)  {  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  }else echo 'connected';echo '<br>';
if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])) 
?>  
        <div id="imagel">
        <img class="imagel" src="../images/logos/logo2.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="studio table" />
        </div>
        <div id="textr">

        <form name="tableofevents" method="post" action="adminhome.php">
        Name of Event(Maximum of 83 characters): <input type="text" name="noe"/>
        <br>
        Event Description (Maximum of 288 characters): <input type="text" name="eventdescription"/>
        <br>
        Date of Event: <input type="text" name="date"/>
        <br>
        Ticket Price: <input type="text" name="price"/>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" text="submit"/>
        </form>
```

Processing Page:

```
<?php

$hostname = 'localhost';
$user='******';
$pass='***********';  
$dbname='sth420';
$handler = new PDO('mysql:host='.$hostname.';dbname='.$dbname,$user,$pass);

$dbh = mysql_connect ($hostname.';dbname='.$dbname, $user, $pass);

if (!$dbh)  {  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  }
else echo 'connected';echo '<br>';


if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])) 
{
    $username=$_COOKIE['username'];
    $password=$_COOKIE['password'];

    $sql='SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID=:id';   
    $results = $handler->prepare($sql);
    $results->execute([':id' => $username]);
    $row = $results->fetch();
    if($row!=null)



    {
        $pword = $row['Password'];
        if($pword == $password)
        {
            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                $noe=$_POST['noe'];
                $ed=$_POST['eventdescription'];
                $date=$_POST['date'];
                $price=$_POST['price'];



                    $sql='INSERT INTO ismievents ( title, evtdesc, dandt, price ) VALUES(0, :noe, :eventdescription, :date, :price)';
                    mysql_error()
                    $results = $handler->prepare($sql);
                    $results->execute([':noe' => $noe, ':eventdescription' => $ed, ':date' => $date, ':price' => $price]);
                    $handler = null;
                    header('Location: events.html');


            }
        }
    }
}
if (!mysql_query($sql,$dbh))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($dbh);
require_once('adminhome.html');

?>
```

Comment: Why do you have a DB connection on the form page? Make sure you include error handling at each step in the process (on instantiating `$handler`, on preparing the statement, on executing the statement, etc. and log out the errors so you can see exactly where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing PDO and `mysql_connect()`.  That is invalid, as they are incompatible APIs.  Remove all references to `mysql_*()` and stick only with your PDO statements.  You have basically duplicated every PDO statement with an incorrect call to `mysql_query()` but you should have none of `mysql_connect(), mysql_query(), mysql_error(), mysql_fetch_*()`.

Refer to [the manual on PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to see the many examples.

I see a mismatch between column counts here.  You list 4 columns, but the `VALUES ()` list contains 5:

```
// Prepared statemetn looks ok...
$sql='INSERT INTO ismievents ( title, evtdesc, dandt, price ) VALUES(0, :noe, :eventdescription, :date, :price)';
// But this is meaningless here...
mysql_error()
```

I note also that you are using PHP 5.4 array literals like:

```
$results->execute([':noe' => $noe, ':eventdescription' => $ed, ':date' => $date, ':price' => $price]);
```

Hopefully you are actually running this code in PHP 5.4.

Really, you need to take this code back to the drawing board to purge it of the incompatibilities between PDO and `mysql_*()`. After that, you will be able to narrow down other problems with it.

A final note here, it is *really* inadvisable to store a password in `$_COOKIE`.  On a successful login, instead store a logged in state in `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Yes, use either PDO or mysql_* (or mysqli-*) functions not a mix of both.  I would suggest that you use PDO or mysqli_*, as mysql_* functions are deprecated and if I was a teacher professor and had a student turn in something using mysql-* I would pretty much condemn that submittal to a failing grade.

Comment: hi thanks for the replies, i am fixing the mysql/ PDO errors, the mismatch between the columns and the values is that, the first value is an auto incrementing ID column, do i still need to add that?

Comment: No,  you do not need to include the auto increment id at all.

Comment: if (!$handler)  {  die('Could not connect: ' . PDO_error());  }
else echo 'connected';echo '<br>'; 
    
if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])) 
{
 
 $username=$_COOKIE['username'];
 $password=$_COOKIE['password'];
 
 $sql='SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID=:id';   
 $results = $handler->prepare($sql);
 $results->execute([':id' => $username]);
 $row = $results->fetch();
 if($row!=null)

Comment: this is as high up in my code that the connection is good. so it isnt even conecting to the database on this page, but i have used the same code on another page and it connects fine?

Comment: Unless you have written a custom one, there is no such function `PDO_error()`, which is a fatal error in the code. You need to have error reporting enabled and displayed while developing.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`